# Generate random color apart from black

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using this method in my Xamarin project to generate random colors

```
Random random = new Random();
public string BoColor
{
    get
    {
        return String.Format("#{0:X6}", random.Next(0x808080) & 0x7E7E7E);
    }
}
```

but I'm expecting to generate colors without black color, help will be appreciated in this regard.

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: You want a random color, however you don't want to include black?

Comment: Just for clarification, did you design the method to generate colors apart of black, or did you design your method to create *any* random color and want to exclude black post hoc?

Comment: What qualifies as black for you? Is it only *pure black* or is `#010101` black enough to qualify as black? If so, then I'd like to know where the threshold is.

Comment: yes that's true but its better if it can generates colors not related to black ( i mean colors looks very dark like black for example colors like #010101 ) like @Paul Kertscher mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend on what @Gaurang Dave said, you can set your own threshold with the `IsAlmostBlack(string color)`:

```
    private static string GenerateColor()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        string color;
        do
        {
            color = $"#{random.Next(0x808080) & 0x7E7E7E:X6}";
        }
        while (IsAlmostBlack(color));

        return color;
    }

    private static bool IsAlmostBlack(string color)
    {
        // #XX0000
        int red = int.Parse(color.Substring(1, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        // #00XX00
        int green = int.Parse(color.Substring(3, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        // #0000XX
        int blue = int.Parse(color.Substring(5, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);

        // Checks if all values are under a certain value (here 50[decimal])
        return red < 0x32 && green < 0x32 && blue < 0x32;
    }
```

You could of course also use decimals:

```
        // Checks if all values are under a certain value (here 50[decimal])
        return red < 50 && green < 50 && blue < 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways to achieve this. You can develop a method like this

```
static string generateColor()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    string color = string.Empty;
    do
    {
        color = string.Format("#{0:X6}", random.Next(0x808080) & 0x7E7E7E);
    }
    while (color == "#000000");

    return color;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your support , i used the above method but still its generating colors related to black fro example #010101, is their way that we can generate colors without very dark colors like #010101, #000000, etc

Comment: @PanWeerasekara is all right if I change `random.Next(0x808080) & 0x7E7E7E` this line to generate light colors?

Comment: the reason i use the  random.Next(0x808080) & 0x7E7E7E is only to generate dark colors ( remove all the light colors )